# What the negative past for the modal verb 'have to'?

Tags: periphrastic-modals

What the negative past for the modal verb 'have to'?

affirmative sentence (present simple)

> He *has to* do it

negative sentence (present simple)

> He *doesn't have to* do it

positive sentence (past simple)

> He *had to* do it

**negative sentence (past simple)**

> He **didn't have to** do it - **IS IT RIGHT?**

Comment: That's exactly right. You will occasionally encounter older writers treating lexical *HAVE* as an auxiliary--*He hadn't any money*, *He hadn't to do it*--but that's virtually dead today.

Comment: And by the way: *HAVE* in the idiom *HAVE to VERB* is not a modal verb: *modal verb* is a technical term which designates the very small class of 'defective' auxiliary verbs which have only two finite forms and no non-finite forms: *can/could, may/might, must, shall/should, will/would*.

Comment: @StoneyB should I name 'have to' as the _'a semimodal verb'_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's right.  It follows the normal conjugation for "to have".

> He couldn't find a date so he had to go to the dance with his sister.
>   At the last minute he got a date so that he didn't have to go to the dance with his sister.
>
> While they were traveling they had to eat all kinds of unusual things.
>   While they were traveling they didn't have to eat anything unusual.